# How to store a list of multiple Swift files and execute them independently

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to create a small tutorial project for improving the coding style in Swift. Each lesson will contain two code examples, one for before and one for after.

So in total, I will have around 20 files that I would like to run individually and independently of the others.

Any suggestions on how to store all these?

Ideally, they should all belong to a project, but I am not figuring out how to run them separately.

Thank you

Here is an example of "before" (bad) code:

```
//a flying saucer
struct X {
    var x: Float //the horizontal coordinate of the center of the flying saucer
    var y: Float //the vertical coordinate of the center of the flying saucer
    var r: Float //the radius of the starship
}

//function finding out if two flying saucers colided
func collision(x: X, y: X) -> Bool {
    return abs(x.x - y.x) < x.r + y.r
}


//testing code
let x = X(x: 10, y: 10, r: 10)
let y = X(x: 12, y: 13, r: 5)
let z = X(x: 100, y: 50, r: 20)

print(collision(x: x, y: y))
print(collision(x: x, y: z))
print(collision(x: x, y: z))
```

Comment: One workspace different targets/xcodeproj?

Comment: What is the contents of these files? Data, Swift code, or something else? It's pretty simple to store twenty files in a project and pull them one-by-one or on-demand. But the best answer probably is a result of knowing what the contents of each file are.

Comment: If you really want them to be independent of each other like @Larme mentioned have a workspace with different projects. OR if the idea is to just separate them, classify them in folders in one project like "Example 1, 2 ..n" but when your app starts load a Table View with all of the examples listed out as cells. Just hook up the respective controller on each cell tap. It works like an index for all of your tutorials.

Comment: I added an example.